# Compute max memory bandwidth of a processor

Tags: memory, cpu, bandwidth

I'm reading this CPU specification: http://ark.intel.com/products/67356/Intel-Core-i7-3612QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz-rPGA

It says the CPU has **2 channels**. So I think it has **2 memory controller** inside. Then the max memory bandwidth should be 1.6GHz * 64bits * 2 * 2 = 51.2 GB/s if the supported DDR3 RAM are 1600MHz. But the specification says its max memory bandwidth is 25.6 GB/s.
I multiplied two 2s here, one for the Double Data Rate, another for the memory channel.

Is it the problem of the specification? or I have some miss understanding?

Comment: Why do you have *two* factors of 2 there ? One for DDR and one for the presumed two memory controllers ?

Comment: Yes. one for the Double Data Rate, another for the memory channel number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Double data rate memory specs usually already take into account that its effective frequency is doubled. "1600 MHz memory" [really runs on 800 Mhz](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_data_rate#Relation_of_bandwidth_and_frequency), so you can leave out one factor of 2 from your calculation.